# Focus timepicker by tapping on image in a list in xamarin.forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, focus, timepicker

I have a listview, which consists of the stack layout with Time Picker and the image. What I want is while tapping on the image the timePicker should focus. If those controls are not in a listview they can be access by X:Name but how can I focus when they are in Listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a custom ViewCell

#### CustomCell.xaml

```
<ViewCell.View>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="ImagTest" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            <Picker x:Name="pickerTest"
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell.View>
```

#### Then, in CustomCell.xaml.cs

```
public partial class CustomCell : ViewCell
    {
        public CustomCell ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pickerTest.Focus();
        }
    }
```

#### Define the namespace in your listview page

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProject;assembly=YourProject"
```

#### In your listview

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:CustomCell/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Bruno Caceiro, but is there any way to do it from MVVM

Comment: What do you mean from MVVM

Comment: I mean, I am binding the itemSource for the list from viewModel and giving the visibilities for some controls from the Model, in the same way is there any way to give focus property for timepicker from viewModel